# Display Results from PDO

Tags: php, sql, oop, pdo

This is probably an absolute noob question and because I am new to PDO I can't really understand the other solutions that are posted.
All I am trying to do is display the results of a query returned by a fetchall in a database calss

I have set up an index page that creates an instance of a database class and calls the method getData, which runs a FetchAll and returns the records.

```
$db = new database($pdo);
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM fruit';
$rows = $db->getData($sql);
$count = $db->getCount($sql);
echo $count;
print_r($rows);
foreach($rows as $fruit){
        echo $fruit->'fruitName';
}
```

The code all runs and the $rows array is populated with the result of get data, and the count has a result of 8 which is correct but I cannot output the results with the foreach!

The database class is here for reference:

```
class database
{
    function __construct($pdo)
    {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }
    function getData($sql)
    {
        $query = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute();
        return $query->fetchAll();
    }
    function getCount($sql)
    {
        $query = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute();
        return $query->rowCount();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this: `print_r($rows);` output?

Comment: Your `database` class really doesn't add anything worthwhile over pure `PDO`. In fact, you're executing the query twice completely unnecessarily because your `database` class as written prevents you from fetching both the row count and the data with the same query. Get rid of that, use `PDO` directly.

Comment: The `print_r ` was giving something like this `Array ( [0] => Array ( [fruitid] => 1 [0] => 1 [fruitName] => apple [1] => apple [colour] => green [2] => green`. I can see the ineffeciency of the code thank you. I actually only added the count method so that I could double check I was getting the correct data out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any error trying to echo `$fruit->'fruitName'`, try to access it by array, like `$fruit['fruitName']`. That's how PDO's `fetchAll()` method returns the results.

However, you can also specify that you want an array of objects, by passing `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` as first parameter of the `fetchAll()` method, and the class name as second parameter.

See here : http://php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Hope this helps !

Comment: YES! That was it, not `$fruit->'fruitName'`, i needed`$fruit['fruitName']`. Honestly I thought I had tried every combination of syntax possible!Thank you

Comment: You're welcome, don't hesitate to mark your question as resolved if it's what you were looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your database class makes no sense. Because **it is not using prepared statements at all** and because it makes you run the same query twice for no reason.
2. Default fetch mode in PDO is `FETCH_BOTH`, which won't give you an object.
3. Class properties in PHP are addressed without quotes.

So make your code this way

```
class database
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $host = '127.0.0.1';
        $db   = 'test';
        $user = 'root';
        $pass = '';
        $charset = 'utf8';

        $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
        $opt = [
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ,
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
        ];
        $this->pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
    }
    function query($sql, $data = NULL)
    {
        $query = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute($data);
        return $query;
    }
}

$db = new database();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM fruit';
$rows = $db->query($sql)->fetchAll();
$count = count($rows);
echo $count;
print_r($rows);
foreach($rows as $fruit){
        echo $fruit->fruitName;
}
```

Recently I wrote an article, [Your first database wrapper's childhood diseases](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes), which you may find worth reading.

Comment: thank you, I'll have a little go with this later. Could I just ask the line `$data = NULL` means that `$data` is default to `NULL` but I could include an array of parameters?

Comment: @DavidJohn yes, exactly. You can omit it when there are no placeholders, and you can send an array with parameters if you have placeholders in your query. It is very convenient.